# Cannot open camera on raspberry pi - VIDIOC_STREAMON: Invalid argument and VIDIOC_DQBUF

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, camera

I have the following python script to handle camera input

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
def run_vc():
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


if cap is None or not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error opening video")
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_term_handler)

try:
    while True:
        retval, img = cap.read()
        .... # do some stuff
    
    # free camera object and exit
    print("app finish")
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

except KeyboardInterrupt: # If CTRL+C is pressed, exit cleanly:
    print("Keyboard interrupt")
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

except ValueError:
    print("some error" + str(ValueError))
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def signal_term_handler(sigNum, frame):
    # on receiving a signal initiate a normal exit
    raise SystemExit('terminating')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_vc()
```

And if the raspberry shutdown unexpectedly and I try to run the code once again I get following error

```
VIDIOC_STREAMON: Invalid argument
```

So there are maybe some handles or resources to be freed.
Can anyone help?

Comment: please explain "the raspberry shutdown unexpectedly". what does it mean, what does it not mean?

Comment: for example due to power conditions so the camera handle is not being released.

Comment: when the whole system reboots, all the handles in the world have no meaning anymore. to assert any relation there is nonsensical. -- worst case (hypothetical), some peripheral (the camera?) stays in a strange state that isn't initialized properly by the driver, so everything needs a complete power-down instead of just a reset.

Comment: It does complete power-down when power conditions are off (in some cases of emergency shutdown of external supply for example). But if the camera is in invalid state it is possible to reset it (via kernel call)?
Other applications are also unable to work - for example command
`raspivid -v -o vid.h264 -t 1000` 
hangs and after some timeout reports error like
`VIDIOC_DQBUF: Resource temporarily unavailable`
so I have a suspition there's something not available in kernel.

Comment: if you can replicate this without any OpenCV (try it), then that's a purely raspberry pi/pi camera issue. you should then report the issue to the appropriate project.

Comment: Finally it shows up that it was bad connection. I needed to pull and push the cable several times to find good position and avoid this error.